# How to highlight a focused node in a tree in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose we have a tree structure rendered to a DOM tree like following:

```
<ul>
    <li>Outer
        <ul>
            <li>Inner
                <ul>
                    <li>Inner Inner</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

We want to highlight the "focused" (mouse hover) node, the point here is, when an Inner node is highlighted, it's parents should not be highlighted.

With jQuery, you can access parent nodes and the solution is very straightforward http://jsfiddle.net/D7jwq/2/:

```
$("li").mouseover(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass("red").parents().removeClass("red");
    e.stopPropagation();
}).mouseout(function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("red");
});
```

But how to get the similar effect in ReactJS?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for this at all, it can (and must) be solved with css

```
li:hover {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Refer to https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp for more details.

Comment: *"must"*? why??

Comment: Maybe I haven't describe it clear. The point here is, when an Inner node is highlighted, it's parents should not be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

React also has mouseover and mouseout events https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

jquery `$("li")` implicitly set those events to all `<li>` elements.

In React, you have to explicitly set those events to your `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, I managed a state "focused" for every node, and update this state when the mouse events `over` and `out` is triggered. Notice that `leave` is not triggered when you move from parent node to child node, you can observe the console output for different between these events.

And `ev.stopPropagation()` is used to make sure that **only one node is focused at the same time**.

Different from the jQuery approach, you can not access a node's parent, so you have to manage state for each node.

App.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

class MouseEventTest extends React.Component {
  public render() {

    class Echo extends React.Component<{title}, {focused}> {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {focused: false}
        this.echo = this.echo.bind(this)
      }
      public echo(title, evName) {
        return (ev) => {
          ev.preventDefault()
          ev.stopPropagation()
          console.log(title, evName, ev)
          if (['over', 'out'].indexOf(evName) >= 0) {
            this.setState({focused: (['enter', 'over'].indexOf(evName) >= 0)})
          }
        }
      }
      public render() {
        const title = this.props.title
        return (
          <div style={{display: "block", color: (this.state.focused ? "red" : "inherit"), background: '#3bdb7b50'}}
            onClick={this.echo(title, 'click')}
            onMouseEnter={this.echo(title, 'enter')}
            onMouseOver={this.echo(title, 'over')}
            onMouseOut={this.echo(title, 'out')}
            onMouseLeave={this.echo(title, 'leave')}
          >
            {"(" + title + " "}
            {this.props.children}
            {" " + title + ")"}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    return (
      <Echo title="Lv1">
        <Echo title="Lv2">
          <Echo title="Lv3">
            abc
          </Echo>
        </Echo>
      </Echo>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <MouseEventTest />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

To execute the above code, you can run `create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts` to init an directory, and replace `src/App.tsx` with the above code. and maybe the following config is needed.

tslint.json

```
{
  "rules": {
    "no-console": false,
    "max-classes-per-file": false,
    "comment-format": false,
    "jsdoc-format": false
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
  }
}
```